# Wi-Fi peer-to-peer API in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, wifi

The OS X AirDrop feature allows a direct Wi-Fi connection to a nearby Mac, one that's concurrent with any connection to a Wi-Fi AP. It's variously said to use Wi-Fi IBSS mode (aka ad hoc) or Wi-Fi Direct.

Is there an API (possibly undocumented driver commands) to control concurrent Wi-Fi P2P?

I believe AirDrop uses IBSS since it works on Macs pre-dating Wi-Fi Direct, and uses TLS which is necessary since IBSS only provides WEP. But perhaps it uses Wi-Fi Direct if both nodes support it?

Alternatively, what are the best resources for undocumented OS X APIs?

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/lion-server-filesharing-protocols-101.html), AFP is the most common networking protocol for Apple Macintosh. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/AFP_Reference/Reference/reference.html) might be the documentation you're looking for. Not sure if this "AirDrop" is just an extension of this feature, if so you may be able to use Netatalk, Jaffer or another [third-party api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Filing_Protocol#Third-party_implementations).

Comment: AirDrop may well use parts of it under the hood (Although it doesnt really seem to use much of the functionality of Netatalk. It *seems* to just transfer individual files rather than a full directory structuer), but theres a separate wireless part on a different network layer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising: https://serverfault.com/a/54256

Generally, if you're poking around in system libraries, you might find [class-dump](http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/) useful... You can also use the `nm` command to dump symbols from libraries/frameworks.

I assume Wi-Fi Direct is a requirement of AirDrop, according to MacWorld [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1144061/wifidirect.html), although Late 2008 seems a bit early for WiFi Direct.

Apple [says](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4783) the supported models are

- MacBook Pro (Late 2008 or newer)*
- MacBook Air (Late 2010 or newer)
- MacBook (Late 2008 or newer)*
- iMac (Early 2009 or newer)
- Mac Mini (Mid 2010 or newer)
- Mac Pro (Early 2009 with AirPort Extreme card, or Mid 2010)